# Linking vs creating a new object using GAE and JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am build a web service using Google App Engine and JDO data store.
Everything works well and I have a pretty good understanding of how the pieces fit together.

**The issue I'm having is as follows:**
When I am inserting a new product class which has an unowned related object of store, it will create a new store object even though that store already exists.

What I would like to happen, is if json is submitted with store data that already exists, it will just link the new product to the already existing store instead of creating a duplicate store with a new id.

I've tried adding `@Unique(name = "STORE_COMPOSITE_IDX", members = {"key", "name"})` to the store class thinking that if the name was already present it would link to that store, but this does not work.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new object it has no identity so is in "TRANSIENT" state. If you pass that to the persistence mechanism it will persist it as new (either as the argument to makePersistent, or as a field of an object passed to makePersistent).

If you want to link to an existing object you should retrieve the existing object (pm.getObjectById) that you want to relate it to and set the field of your new object to that. The retrieved object will be in PERSISTENT or HOLLOW state in this case. When you persist your other object it will find the existent object and so just link to it in the DB.

Read up on object lifecycle states. All in the JDO spec or any decent JDO docs (and GAE docs are NOT "decent JDO docs")